# jQuery populate items into a Select using jQuery ajax json, php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, post

I have a select field. I must fill with options taken from a mysql table.
Here is some little php code I have done using codeigniter framework

```
$idcateg = trim($this->input->post('idcategory'));
$array1 = array(
    'result' => $idcateg
);
echo json_encode($array1);
```

Now, the jQuery call...

```
$.post("<?=base_url()?>index.php/rubro/list_ajax/", { 
    'idcategory' : idc },
    function(data){
        alert(data.result);
    }, "json");
```

The code works fine. When I call the post, I get the categoryid as a result.
Now, I should modify the code above, so I can do:

- post the ajax call sending the category id. this is done
- get subcategories for this category, and build the array *
- json_encode the array and echo *
- get results back in jQuery ajax call, decode and build the < select > field *

The array should be built with each element having a sub-array with id and name, right?
Thanks a lot in advance for any help

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's not much different.

```
$idcateg = trim($this->input->post('idcategory'));
$result = array();
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($idcateg);
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE category = $id");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  $result[] = array(
    'id' => $row['subcatid'],
    'desc' => $row['description'],
  );
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

with:

```
$.post("<?=base_url()?>index.php/rubro/list_ajax/", { 
  'idcategory' : idc },
  function(data) {
    var sel = $("#select");
    sel.empty();
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
      sel.append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].desc + '</option>');
    }
  }, "json");
```

Comment: hi cletus. Worked perfect. Can you tell me now what if nothing is returned? (i.e. mysql returns empty).. how can i tell if result is empty?
thanks

Comment: data.lenght will be 0

Comment: Or, instead of the `for`, could be: `$.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    sel.append($("<option>").val(data[key].id).text(data[key].desc));
                });`;

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  You want to pass back a JSON-encoded array of objects containing name/value pairs.  Then you can create your select iteratively using these.

```
$.post("<?=base_url()?>index.php/rubro/list_ajax/",
    {'idcategory' : idc },
    function(data){
        var select = $('#selectName').empty();
        $.each(data.values, function(i,item) {
            select.append( '<option value="'
                                 + item.id
                                 + '">'
                                 + item.name
                                 + '</option>' ); 
        });
    }, "json");
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also just use $().load() and have your PHP code generate the `<option>` tags

```
  $return = "";
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $value = $row['value'];
    $text = $row{'text'];
    $return .= "<option value='$value'>$text</option>\n";
  }
print $return;
}
```

...

```
$('#select').load("<?=base_url()?>index.php/rubro/list_ajax/");
```

Comment: Awesome tip/idea... Will try it!! Thanks Scott !!

Comment: be aware that according to my experience this solution may not work on IE8 and below due to a bug in DOM manipulation using innerHTML (http://webbugtrack.blogspot.it/2007/08/bug-274-dom-methods-on-select-lists.html) - however it works well on other browsers, including IE 9+

Answer (score 1):

Try the following Code.

In Controller ---------

```
public function AjaxTest() {

            $rollNumber = $this->input->post('rollNumber');
            $query = "";

            if($rollNumber !="")
            {
               $query = $this->welcome_model->get_students();
            }
            else
            {
               $query = $this->welcome_model->get_students_informationByRoll($rollNumber);
            }

            $array = array($query);
            header('Content-Type: application/json', true);
            echo json_encode($array);

        }
```

In View Add a Select Option

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearchRoll" name="roll" value="" />
<input type="button" name="btnSubmit" value="Search Students" onclick="return CheckAjaxCall();"/>

     <select id="myStudents">
                <option>
                    --Select--
                </option>
            </select>
```

Now Scripts ----

```
function CheckAjaxCall()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/AjaxTest',                    
                    dataType:'json',
                    data:{rollNumber: $('#txtSearchRoll').val()},                    
                    cache:false,
                    success:function(aData){ 

                        $('#myStudents').get(0).options.length = 0;
                        $('#myStudents').get(0).options[0] = new Option("--Select--", "0");        

                        $.each(aData, function(i,item) {
                        $('#myStudents').get(0).options[$('#myStudents').get(0).options.length] = new Option(item[i].Name, item[i].roll);
                                                                                                            // Display      Value
                    });

                    },
                    error:function(){alert("Connection Is Not Available");}
                });

                return false;
            }
```

Enjoy the code....