# Auto populate from SQL server using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

For a normal text box I wrote this:

```js
$SUL("#txtlinkid").val(json[0].linkurl);
```

The information is prefilling automatically from the database.

For a dropdown I wrote this:

```js
$SUL("#txteventitleid").val(json[0].eventtitle);
```

But it is not prefilling from the database.

What is the correct procedure for dropdown?

Comment: If the object with id  `txteventitleid` is a dropdown (select) then it will not work. to fill the select with options you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1745745/2943218 It's simular but you need to change it just a bit

Comment: For the dropdown, are you trying to ***select*** a value, or ***add*** all options to it?

Comment: 2 questions: 1) what is the HTML for your "dropdown" - you've named it with prefix `txt` which indicates it's a textbox, not a `select`.     2) *exactly* what is the ID of the "dropdown"?  Your property is `eventtitle`, but your code ID is `eventitleid` - looks like it should be `eventtitleid`  (2 Ts in the middle).  This is why we ask for minimal code - looks like it's just a typo.

Comment: If the `<option>`s already exist and it is a `<select id='eventitleid>` then `$("#txteventitleid").val(new_value)` should work, here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/msuedwnc/ but it won't add new `<option>`s for you.